# asp.net/C#: Handle datetime if null using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have null values in database specifically for Good Expiry Date, which is the field is:`good_expiryDate`.

What i want is to handle it in this way:
If `good_expiryDate` is null i want to present it as "" or "-", if it has value it will show the value retrieved from database?

the LINQ query i write is like this, but it return `MinValue` if `good_expiryDate` is `null`(this is what i tried to do).

```
var query = (from cd in db.CDIndexes
             join gds in db.Goods on cd.cdin_CDIndexID equals gds.good_CDIndexId 
             join itms in db.Items on gds.good_ItemsID equals itms.item_ItemsID

            where
            cd.cdin_CompanyId==c.Comp_CompanyId&&
            (
                gds.good_RemainCBM > 0 ||
                gds.good_RemainWT > 0 ||
                gds.good_RemainPackages > 0 ||
                gds.good_RemainVolumeWT > 0
            )
            &&
            itms.item_ItemsID==customerId

            select new DataItem
            {
                 depNumber=(int)cd.cdin_Serial,
                 ItemDesc=gds.good_Name,
                 gdExpiryDate =(DateTime) gds.good_expiryDate==null?DateTime.MinValue: (DateTime)gds.good_expiryDate,
                 InvoicBalanceUnits = (decimal) gds.good_RemainPackages,
                 WTBal=(decimal)gds.good_RemainWT,
                 VolWT=(decimal)gds.good_RemainVolumeWT
            }
       );
return query.ToList();
```

> Update: good_expiryDate is type of Datetime, nullable in database

Comment: does your `good_expiryDate` is a nullable datetime ??

Comment: `gdExpiryDate` should be string type. In this case you should use `(DateTime)gds.good_expiryDate == null ? "-" : ((DateTime)gds.good_expiryDate).ToString("G")`

Comment: May be you can try `good_expiryDate = good_expiryDate.HasValue ? good_expiryDate.Value : null;`

Comment: @MohitShrivastava yes it's

Comment: Can you compare with `System.DBNull.Value` instead of `null`

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki cannot convert datetime to string error and ToString("g") overload error

Comment: @faresAyyad so use only `ToString()`

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki also cannot convert string to system.datetime

Comment: Can you change `good_expiryDate` to be of type `Nullable<DateTime>` in your code?

Comment: @faresAyyad So if it nullable DateTime type you cant assign empty string or _"-"_. Consider validating `gdExpiryDate` on your view.  If null set _"-"_ instead `gdExpiryDate.Value`. If it not nullable set min value and also validate it in view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that `gdExpiryDate` is of type `string`.

Then change this line

```
gdExpiryDate =(DateTime) gds.good_expiryDate==null?DateTime.MinValue: (DateTime)gds.good_expiryDate,
```

to

```
gdExpiryDate = gds.good_expiryDate==null? "-" : ((DateTime)gds.good_expiryDate).ToString(),
```

Comment: You only mentioned about your requirement like this **If good_expiryDate is null i want to present it as "" or "-", if it has value it will show the value retrieved from database**.  If you want to display `-` then it has to be string obviously. @faresAyyad

Comment: I am speaking about `gdExpiryDate` and not `good_expiryDate`. `good_expiryDate` can be date time. But the `gdExpiryDate` should be string in order to keep the "-" value in it. @faresAyyad

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful

Comment: Welcome. Glad to help.

Comment: but how can i present it as dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Use `DateTime.ParseExact` like this `DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` or to directly convert to string use this `DateTime.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy")`

Answer (score 0):

Change `gdExpiryDate` type to `string` type and write like this:

```
    select new DataItem
             {
                 depNumber=(int)cd.cdin_Serial,
                 ItemDesc=gds.good_Name,
                 gdExpiryDate = gds.good_expiryDate == null ? "" :  gds.good_expiryDate.Value.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy"),
                 InvoicBalanceUnits = (decimal) gds.good_RemainPackages,
                 WTBal=(decimal)gds.good_RemainWT,
                 VolWT=(decimal)gds.good_RemainVolumeWT
             }
```

Comment: I can't change the database field.